If $F_\bullet$ is a free resolution of a finitely generated module, is the identity map on $F_\bullet$ homotopic to $0$?
I would like to show that if $F_\bullet$ is a free resolution of some finitely generated $R$-module $M$, then the identity map on $F_\bullet$ homotopic to the zero map on $F_\bullet$.
For this, we need to construct a chain homotopy $s_i: F_i \to F_{i+1}$.
However, I am not sure how to construct such maps.
Is this possible?

This would imply that for any right exact functor $Q:\mathsf{RMod}\to\mathsf{Ab}$, $L^\ast Q(M)=0$ in positive degree. Since you're really saying $F\simeq0$ and chain homotopies are preserved by additive functors. In particular, you'd be saying that all finitely generated $R$-modules have vanishing (higher) torsion groups. This is horribly false; for a really nice ring $R$ such as $R=\Bbb Z$ and a very simple f.g. $M$ like $\Bbb Z/2$, your assertion is already false. $0\to\Bbb Z\overset{2}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to 0$ is not a contractible complex, because $1/2$ does not exist.
I would wager that your belief is only correct for $R$ a field (but I'm not sure even then, haven't checked), which is a very strong assertion.

Applying the same argument to functors $\operatorname{Hom}_R({-}, N)$, you would get that $\operatorname{Ext}^i_R(M, N) = 0$ for each $i > 0$, so every $R$-module is projective.

It's not true over a field, either. The free resolution of a vector space $V$ is just $0 \to V \to 0$.

@JohnPalmieri I was considering, as in your answer, "$M$ to be part of" the complex being considered contractible or not. Then I think, but haven't actually checked, it is true over fields. I'll edit to clarify

@JohnPalmieri $0\to V\to0$ isn't a resolution because it isn't exact. You probably meant  $0\to V\to V\to0$, but that is null-homotopic.

@AndreasBlass this comes down to mild terminological clash over whether or not the resolution's complex is augmented or not, which changes context to context

I think if every module is projective, then every short exact sequence splits, so $R$ would be a semisimple ring.  If $R$ is also assumed to be commutative, then that means $R$ is a finite product of fields.  (Of course, the problem is restricted to finitely generated modules; I'm not sure if that destroys the proof.)  It wouldn't be too surprising to me if the statement was true for $R$ a finite product of fields.

@AndreasBlass see for example https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/math538-fall2011/HomologicalNotes.pdf: some people use "free resolution" to denote the free modules and the maps between them, not $M$. Then there is a quasi-isomorphism from the chain complex ("free resolution") $F_*$ to the complex consisting of $M$ concentrated in degree $0$.

@JohnPalmieri I agree that people disagree on whether to include $M$ in its resolution. But, as far as I can see, for a vector space $V$ over a field (or indeed for any free module) the obvious resolution would be $0\to V\to V$ (or maybe $0\to V\to V\to0$) under the "include $M$ convention and just $0\to V$ under the "exclude $M$" convention.

@AndreasBlass I literally provided a link where the trailing $0$ is included in the definition of a free resolution.

As noted already by @FShrike, the statement is false.
Do you intend to include the module $M$ as part of the free resolution or not? Consider the case with $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

If not, then the free resolution $F_{*}$ will have homology equal to $M$ in degree 0, and so it can't be contractible: it can't have the identity map chain homotopic to the zero map. In the particular case in question, the resolution is $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$.

If so, first I would discourage this usage — see below — but if you insist on it, then we get
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0,
$$
and there are no nonzero maps $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ to start constructing a chain homotopy. (If you include the module $M$ as part of the resolution, then you can get the kind of chain homotopy you want if $M$ is itself free, for example if you are working over a field.)


It seems to be more standard in the literature to not include the module in the free resolution: if we have an exact sequence
$$
\dots \to F_1 \to F_0 \to M \to 0
$$
with each $F_i$ free, then the books I looked at (Cartan-Eilenberg, Hilton-Stammbach, Weibel) all say that the free resolution is
$$
\dots \to F_1 \to F_0 \to 0.
$$
(They mostly discuss projective resolutions instead of free ones, but the same considerations apply in both cases.) You can of course extend the sequence to the right just by adding more zeroes, if you want the chain complex to be defined in every integer grading.
I find it helpful to view a free resolution of $M$ as a chain complex $F_*$ of free modules together with a chain map to the chain complex
$$
\dots \to 0 \to 0 \to M \to 0 \to 0 \to \dots
$$
with $M$ in degree 0, such that the chain map induces an isomorphism on homology.

What does $F_*$ being contractible mean? I'm not sure I've run into the definition of a resolution being contractible.

@user5826 it means that the identity map is homotopic to the zero  map.
